# Unity のプレハブの作り方でわからないことがある

Tags: unity2d

[ジャンプアクションゲーム「悪路王」 ゲーム管理オブジェクトを作る | Unityでゲームを作ろう！](https://unity.moon-bear.com/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%80%8C%E6%82%AA%E8%B7%AF%E7%8E%8B%E3%80%8D/%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B/)

というサイトの「キャラクターのプレハブを作る」という項目で

> プレハブの作り方は簡単で、PlayerオブジェクトをPrefabsフォルダにドラッグ＆ドロップするだけです。プレハブが作成されたのを確認したらシーンにあるPlayerオブジェクトは削除してしまって構いません（削除する前によく確認してください）。

とあるのですが、これって以下の画像のように「HierarchyにあるPlayerをProjectのPrefabのファイルに移してHierarchy の方のPlayerは消してください」ってことでいいんですか?

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13220349538